# Finding a key given partial keys

Tags: threshold-cryptography

I'm working through an exam paper for a cryptography exam and I've come across a question I'm unsure on.

Six users have been given the partial keys below

$P(x) = (k + \sum_{i=1}^2 c_ix^i)\bmod{503}$

```
User X Y

1   10 25
2   20 405
3   30 272
4   40 129
5   50 479
6   60 316
```

Reconstruct the secret key K to verify it is 138.

I've tried using Newtons Divided Difference to skip using the formula but that didn't work. I also tried using the Chinese Remainder Theorem on the data but that did not work either. I've tried filling into the equation but I don't think I've been doing it right so any help on how to go about this question would be appreciated

Comment: I edited to try to improve formatting, but it feels like some information is missing. Is $X$ the same thing as $x$? What are the $c_i$ values?

Comment: @mikeazo Perfect thanks. Wasn't sure how to format. And that's the problem I'm not 100% sure. In the question there's a small x and big X so i presume they're different. Also I'm not sure about the ci's i've tried using the ci's to be y's but that didn't work

Comment: I'd guess that $Y = P(x)$. $c_i$ is probably the user ID. No, that doesn't make sense either. Stupid question anyway if this is all the info given. It may rely on some theory we've not been shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the slightly unusual nomenclature, this is [Shamir's secret-sharing scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) with $n=6$ and $k=3$ (i.e., the secret is shared into six pieces, any three of which can be combined to retrieve the secret).

In this case, the pieces are as follows:

$$\begin{align}(x_0, y_0) &= (10, 25) \\
(x_1, y_1) &= (20, 405) \\
(x_2, y_2) &= (30, 272) \\
(x_3, y_3) &= (40, 129) \\
(x_4, y_4) &= (50, 479) \\
(x_5, y_5) &= (60, 316)\end{align}$$

Only three of these are needed to retrieve the secret. As described in the Wikipedia article, this is done by calculating a set of Lagrange basis polynomials:

$$\begin{align}\ell_0 &= \frac{x - x_1}{x_0 - x_1} \cdot \frac{x - x_2}{x_0 - x_2} = \frac{x - 20}{10 - 20} \cdot \frac{x - 30}{10 - 30} = \frac{x^2}{200} - \frac{x}{4} + 3 \\
\ell_1 &= \frac{x - x_0}{x_1 - x_0} \cdot \frac{x - x_2}{x_1 - x_2} = \frac{x - 10}{20 - 10} \cdot \frac{x - 30}{20 - 30} = \frac{-x^2}{100} + \frac{2x}{5} - 3 \\
\ell_2 &= \frac{x - x_0}{x_2 - x_0} \cdot \frac{x - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{x - 10}{30 - 10} \cdot \frac{x - 20}{30 - 20} = \frac{x^2}{200} - \frac{3x}{20} + 1
\end{align}$$

All you need from these polynomials are the constant terms, which are multiplied by the corresponding $y$ terms to give you the secret value:

$$\begin{align}s &= (3 \cdot 25 - 3 \cdot 405 + 1 \cdot 272) \pmod{503} \\
&= 138 \end{align}$$